# Binary Search Tree seg faults in a strange place

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm currently writing a binary search tree to hold a list of songs that I want to be arranged by name. I do the usual recursion, using strcmp to compare the title of the current node of the tree (songs are the nodes) and the title of the song to be added. The code is seg faulting when it reaches my get_title function for Song, which simply returns a char*. I am probably missing something glaringly obvious here, but I'm stumped. My attempts at fixing it have yielded no results. Perhaps you can help me. My code for the binary search tree is as follows:

```
#include "BSTree.h"

BSTree::BSTree() {
next = NULL;
root = NULL;
}

BSTree::BSTree(const BSTree& src) {
next = src.next;
root = src.root;
}

BSTree::~BSTree() {
next = NULL;
root = NULL;
}

void BSTree::add(Song& s) {
root = add_r(root, s);
}

Song* BSTree::add_r(Song* curr, Song& song) {
if(curr = NULL) {
Song* temp = new Song(song);
curr = temp;
cout << "added a new song" << endl;
return curr;
} else if(strcmp(song.get_title(), curr->get_title()) <= 0) {
cout << "went left" << endl;
curr->set_left(add_r(curr->get_left(), song));
} else {
cout << "went right" << endl;
curr->set_right(add_r(curr->get_right(), song));
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line here:

```
if(curr = NULL) {
```

You meant to use `==`.  Currently, your code changes `curr` to be NULL, then evaluates to `false`.  So control passes to the next `if` which calls `curr->get_title()` on the NULL pointer.  The result is a segfault before the program reaches any of the debug statements you put in.

Comment: As an extra observation, not all control paths in your `add_r` function return a value.  You *must* return `curr` at the end of the function or you will corrupt your tree.  You might also want to consider using case-insensitive comparison (stricmp) and think about what to do if you insert a song with the same name as one already in the tree.